# I've just been made the victim of a vicious character assassination in an answer

Tags: discussion, support

Somebody just registered named "www.tenstringguitar.INFO".

He's posted two "answers" to this question

[What are the advantages of Narciso Yepes' 10 stringed guitar?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/6137/1044)

both involving ugly insults and attacks at everybody who posted answers.

Obviously this guy is knowledgeable about his subject matter, but he's vicious and insulting and also obviously a troll, because he hasn't posted anything else on this site other than these attacks.

I've never been in this situation before but this user needs to be banned. Can somebody please look into that?

Comment: Regardless of how badly you've been victimized, nothing is gained by calling someone else a 'blowhard' or 'flaming jerk.' Argumentum ad hominem is not necessary to prove that the user's behavior was unacceptable.

Answer (score 9):

Good timing; I had just dealt with it.  In the future, flagging the relevant post(s) as spam/offensive (or for moderator attention with an explanation) is the best course of action :)

Comment: Thank you, Matthew. I've looked at this guy's web site and he's obviously an authoritative master of the 10-string guitar, who would have much to offer were he not to choose to be a flaming jerk. It's a shame he couldn't simply write a constructive and instructive answer giving his point of view based on his considerable experience and expertise. Instead, he lashed out and attacked in all directions as his first post on a site he's never participated in before. What an unpleasant experience.

Comment: @WheatWilliams Indeed. Calling your post part of a targeted propaganda campaign is incredibly ridiculous.

Comment: I would definitely support the decision to delete, despite possibly losing an authority on this subject, as his attitude was outrageous. Was quite shocking behaviour to see from a new member of the site.

Comment: are you sure he isn't an impersonator? That is very possible.

Answer (score 7):

There's no point in banning the guy.  He just came to speak his mind.  He likely has no intention of coming back.

He's *not* a "troll".

[image: troll]

From wikipedia:

> A troll is someone who posts inflammatory, extraneous, or off-topic messages in an online community, such as an online discussion forum, chat room, or blog, with the ***primary intent* of provoking readers into an emotional response or of otherwise disrupting normal on-topic discussion.**

So, he's not doing that. He's clearly somehow *offended* by the "misinformation" provided on the 10-string guitar (for lack of a better word - I know nothing about the 10-string guitar).  This happens when the guy feels you're belittling his life's work or like his favorite thing ever - (the 10-string guitar), so you hurt his feelings inadvertently.

As a result, he lashed back, and tried to hurt your feelings.

Smooth operator Matthew Read appears to have rectified the entire situation, so I'd consider this case closed.

Comment: I'd add that these attacks are of course through no fault of OP's. Good explanation!

Answer (score 2):

The answer was reposted in a more tempered form, however I still had to edit out a couple of unnecessary confrontational statements. Now I think it has a lot of good content.

Comment: Thanks. I also dealt with the second answer/comment that was posted.

Comment: Thanks for the editing. I was not about to go there myself.